# Python not erasing contents of file with truncate

Tags: python

I am having problems erasing file contents. I have a file with `'ABC'` in it. I open it up and `truncate()` to clear everything from the file and then write new contents to it. But whatever I write just gets appended to what was previously there.

```
>>> handle=open('test.txt', 'r+')
>>> stuff = handle.read()
>>> stuff
'ABC'
>>> handle.truncate()
>>> handle.write('DEF'+stuff)
>>> handle.close()
>>> handle=open('test.txt', 'r+')
>>> handle.read()
'ABCDEFABC'
```

I think I should be getting `'DEFABC'` but instead I get `'ABC'` with `'DEFABC'` appended to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `handle.read()`, you are at the end of the file, so there's nothing to truncate from here. Issue `handle.seek(0)` after `handle.read()`. Then write your data to the file, then truncate if necessary.

Comment: Yes, this is POSIXly correct answer, but python `truncate` does take the size of the file as a parameter, too.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [`truncate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate), the default value is the current position. You need to pass `0`.

> Truncate the file’s size. If the optional size argument is present,
>   the file is truncated to (at most) that size. **The size defaults to the
>   current position.** The current file position is not changed. Note that
>   if a specified size exceeds the file’s current size, the result is
>   platform-dependent: possibilities include that the file may remain
>   unchanged, increase to the specified size as if zero-filled, or
>   increase to the specified size with undefined new content.
>   Availability: Windows, many Unix variants.

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate)

> `file.truncate([size])`
>
> Truncate the file’s size. If the optional size argument is present, the file is truncated to (at most) that size. The size defaults to the current position.

You call `handle.truncate()` after calling `handle.read()`, at which time the current position is the end of the file, so Python truncates the file to its current size, which does nothing.  You need to pass 0 as the argument to `truncate`: `handle.truncate(0)`.

Comment: Using truncate(0) and then writing seems to clear the data but when I then try to write more data it doesn't seem to save